# How to add text in R Markdown when using a LaTeX template?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown, tex

I have added a LaTeX template for my R Markdown document so that I can have a certain title page, but I was planning on writing the rest of the paper in R Markdown, but when I add a LaTeX template and type text in the R Markdown body, when I go to knit to pdf none of the R Markdown text appears but only the template does.

How I could type in R Markdown after using a LaTeX template?

What I have currently is:

```
---
output: 
    pdf_document:
        template: template.tex
---
# abstract
this is just some text
```

Everything below the `---` doesn't appear when I got to knit and this is my problem.

Within template.tex I have:

```tex
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times. Now that you have edited your previous question, it will show up in the reopen queue and users can vote to reopen it

Comment: my bad im new to this stuff so I am still trying to figure out how this works and no the other question wasnt answered

Comment: @ashak04, your first question was only asked 17 hours ago. Please be _patient_. Most of us are volunteers, and it can take some time to get an answer here. When I look at [recent questions tagged with the Markdown tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown) I can see both of your identical answers on my screen at the same time.

Comment: @ashak04, on the other hand, if your first question wasn't answered because it wasn't clear enough (which appears to be the case here since it was voted closed), asking it again the exact same way isn't going to improve things. Please read [ask] and _improve_ your question.